# How do i get bibtex entries from Amazon.com

Tags: citations, bibtex

Has anyone written an interface through which i can get a citation of a book/paper from [amazon.com](http://amazon.com)

Thanks for the suggestions from fellow users. I'm updating the questions to detail in more specifics:

- Citeulike.org issue: I used BibTeX "Export from My library" features. However its    not that accurate..it cannot extract all meta-data from amazon and  complete the bibliographic reference
- Mendeley Desktop : I used http://www.mendeley.com/blog/academic-features/mendeley-bookmarklet-released-one-click-import-from-google-scholar-pubmed-arxiv-acm-ieee-etc/  is a long way round, I want something where I give the URL and it gives me back the bibtex entry

Comment: if you don't get the answer here try on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Firefox, the [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) add-on should be able to store a citation, which you can then export as BibTeX.

Answer (score 6):

For a completely Web based solution with no addons:

**Lead2Amazon**

Go to http://lead.to/amazon/en/?op=bt put ISBN **or** title, choose BibTeX output and will look up in Amazon and generate the BibTeX, as a bonus it will contain the ISBN and the Amazon URL.

**Tungare's ISBN to BibTeX Converter**

Alternative using ISBN only: http://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/ it will generate the BibTeX including the Amazon URL.

**Ottobib**

http://www.ottobib.com, the same but it will not generate the Amazon URL. Can do multiple ISBN searches at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, lead2amazon appears to be defunct at this point.  I get a 403 forbidden error from this link.

Comment: @DavidTresner-Kirsch, it could have been temporarily down, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to zotero and citeulike, there is also [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com). It allows citation extraction from Amazon via a bookmarklet, and has bibtex export and syncing.

Comment: http://www.mendeley.com/blog/academic-features/mendeley-bookmarklet-released-one-click-import-from-google-scholar-pubmed-arxiv-acm-ieee-etc/ ..... long way round, I want something where I give the URL and it gives me back the bibtex entry

Answer (score 0):

[CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org/) is a social bookmarking service with bibtex support (just copy/paste from the webpage), and Post URL (citeulike.org/post_url.adp) seems to do a quite decent job extracting bibliographic metadata from Amazon book pages.

Comment: I used BibTeX Export from My library ... however its not that accurate..it cannot extract all meta-data from amazon and complete the bibliographic reference